# How to clear input after submit with react

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks

how to clear the input inside this code after submit with the button

```
export default function Form({addTask}) {
const [taskInp, setTaskInp] = useState("")
return (
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Write here"
            onChange={e=>{
                setTaskInp(e.target.value)
            }}
        />
        <button onClick={()=> {
            addTask(taskInp)
        }}>Add Task</button>
    </div>
)}
```

I would love to know what is the recommended way please

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539480/react-clearing-an-input-value-after-form-submit and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922508/clear-and-reset-form-input-fields/43922523

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset form elements when form submit.

```
  const handleSubmit = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    addTask(taskInp);
    event.target.reset();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Write here"
            onChange={e=>{
              setTaskInp(e.target.value);
            }}
        />
        <button type="submit">Add Task</button>
    </form>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there sorter way to do it like

Comment: This goes against the one way data flow paradigm encouraged by react. Ideally you should be reseting the component state and let react handle the re-render. That however means making the input a controlled component

Comment: You can also use Formik library. When onsubmit the form formik has the resetForm method. https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik

Comment: your code reset my lists every single submit

Comment: when do you want it reset?

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70362482/17302724 solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

```js
export default function Form({addTask}) {
const [taskInp, setTaskInp] = useState("")
return (
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Write here"
            value={taskInp}
            onChange={e=>{
                setTaskInp(e.target.value)
            }}
        />
        <button onClick={()=> {
            addTask(taskInp)
            setTaskInp("")
        }}>Add Task</button>
    </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React,{useRef} from "react";                               
                                                  
export default function Form(){                                     
 const formRef = useRef(null)
 handleForm = async(event)=>{
  //handle form logic
  ...
  formRef.current.reset();                 
 }
return (
  <>
   <form onSubmit={handleForm}>
    ....
   </form>                                            
  </>                                                 
)
}
```

Building on [msfers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70362252/13827810) answer and refining it for typescript users, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

normaly i do is just resetting the state after the onClick

```html
  <button onClick={()=> {
      addTask(taskInp),
      setTaskInp("")
  }}>Add Task</button>
```

Comment: thanks, this way are not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).